# How do we solve pell-like equations?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

I need to find all solutions $(x,y)∈Z^2$ to the Pell-like equation $x^2-21y^2= 4$

Method I used to solve above problem:-

I solved the pell-equation $x^2-21y^2= 1$ and calculated the possible solutions to the equation and further multiplied the above equation with the initial equation, i.e, $x^2-21y^2= 4$.

But I am still not able to figure out what should I do next? Could someone help me out in this problem?

Comment: The least primitive solution is $(x,y)=(5,1)$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971248/pells-equation-x2-dy2-4).

Comment: Could you please explain it in detail?

Answer (score 1):

This pictorial method is introduced in [CONWAY](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/conwaysens.pdf) and further discussed in [HATCHER](https://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/TN/TNbook.pdf). There is also an  intuitive book by [Weissman](http://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/) with lots of pictures.

Here is the topograph diagram, showing solutions in a fundamental region as well as the automorphism generator. As integer column vectors, all (well, fundamental) solutions to $x^2 - 21 y^2 = 4$   are
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2 \\
0
\end{array}
\right) \; \; , \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
5 \\
1
\end{array}
\right) \; \; , \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
23 \\
5
\end{array}
\right) \; \; . \; \; 
$$
For each of the three, multiply arbitrarily many times by
$$  A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
55 & 252 \\
12 & 55 \\
\end{array}
\right) \; \; . \; \; 
$$
The first three such vectors are
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
110 \\
24
\end{array}
\right) \; \; , \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
527 \\
115
\end{array}
\right) \; \; , \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2525 \\
551  \\
\end{array}
\right) \; \; . \; \;
$$

The next three such vectors are
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
12098 \\
2640
\end{array}
\right) \; \; , \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
57965 \\
12649
\end{array}
\right) \; \; , \; \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
277727 \\
60605  \\
\end{array}
\right) \; \; . \; \;
$$

Put another way, if we put all such $x_n$ and $y_n$  in two ordered sequences,
$$ 2, 5, 23, 110, 527, 2525, 12098, 57965, 277727, 1330670, 6375623, 30547445, \ldots    $$
$$  0, 1, 5, 24, 115, 551, 2640, 12649, 60605, 290376, 1391275, 6665999, \ldots    $$
Cayley-Hamilton tells us
$$ x_{n+6} = 110 x_{n+3} - x_n , $$
$$ y_{n+6} = 110 y_{n+3} - y_n . $$

[image]

Ummm. The continued fraction was not guaranteed to show all the solutions because 4 is larger than half the square root of 21, but this time we are lucky:

Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at [Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4/2216011#2216011)

$$  \sqrt { 21} = 4 +     \frac{  \sqrt {21} - 4 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {21} - 4 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {21} + 4 }{5 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {21} - 1 }{5 } $$
$$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {21} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {21} + 1 }{4 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {21} - 3 }{4 } $$
$$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {21} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {21} + 3 }{3 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {21} - 3 }{3 } $$
$$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {21} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {21} + 3 }{4 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {21} - 1 }{4 } $$
$$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {21} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {21} + 1 }{5 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {21} - 4 }{5 } $$
$$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {21} - 4 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {21} + 4 }{1 } = 8 +  \frac{    \sqrt {21} - 4 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 4 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 8 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 5 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 23 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 32 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 55 }{ 12 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -5 & & 4 & & -3 & & 4 & & -5 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 21 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & 4^2 - 21 \cdot 1^2 = -5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 5 }{ 1 }   & 5^2 - 21 \cdot 1^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }   & 9^2 - 21 \cdot 2^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 23 }{ 5 }   & 23^2 - 21 \cdot 5^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 32 }{ 7 }   & 32^2 - 21 \cdot 7^2 = -5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 55 }{ 12 }   & 55^2 - 21 \cdot 12^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  8  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

After this one must still apply the automorphism matrix arbitrarily many times...

Comment: List all the solutions?

Comment: Explain it more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Given
$x^2-21y^2= 4$ we can see $(5,1)$ as an easy solution where $5^2-21= 4$.
Another observation is

$$x^2-21y^2= 4\implies \frac{x^2-4}{21}=y^2=\frac{x-2}{p}\cdot\frac{x+2}{q}\quad \text{ where }\quad p|x-2\quad\land\quad q|x+2$$

The factors of $21$ are $1,3,7,21$ and trying the cofactors $(1,21)$ we get conflicting answers for what is x.

$$x-2=1\implies x=3\quad \land \quad x+2=21\implies x=19 \lor\\
 x-2=21\implies x=23\quad \land \quad x+2=1\implies x=-1$$

but the other two cofactors do yield consistent results for what is x.

$$x-2=3\implies x=5\quad \land \quad x+2=7\implies x=5$$
and this fits our desire to have integers that, multiplied, yield a square.

$$\frac{x-2}{3}\cdot\frac{x+2}{7}=\frac{5-2}{3}\cdot\frac{5+2}{7}
=\frac{3}{3}\cdot\frac{7}{7}=\frac{21}{21}=1=y^2$$
Only positive integers have been used in this demonstration but the results are the same with $(-5,-1)$ because, multiplied, they become positive.

$$\therefore x^2-21y^2= 4\implies x=\pm5\quad y=\pm 1 $$