# Why are the Fibonacci quotients $\frac{F_{2n}}{F_{2n+1}}$ the only rationals that make $\frac{x}{1 - x - x^2}$ a non-negative integer?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I've been studying [A081018](https://oeis.org/A081018) as part of a programming challenge. Skipping some of the introductory material, the crux of the question is that we have the equation

$$S = \frac{x}{1 - x - x^2}$$

and we want to know which values $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ produce nonnegative integer values of $S$.

A081018 (linked above) asserts that all solutions to this problem are of the form $x = \frac{F_{2n}}{F_{2n+1}}$, resulting in $S = F_{2n} F_{2n+1}$ (where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number, with $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$).

Now, I understand why those $x$ values are solutions to the problem. As a very quick summary, we have

$$S = \frac{\frac{F_{2n}}{F_{2n+1}}}{1 - \frac{F_{2n}}{F_{2n+1}} - \frac{F_{2n}^2}{F_{2n+1}^2}} = \frac{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}{F_{2n+1}(F_{2n+1} - F_{2n}) - F_{2n}^2} = \frac{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}{F_{2n+1}F_{2n-1} - F_{2n}^2} = (-1)^{2n} F_{2n} F_{2n+1} = F_{2n} F_{2n+1}$$

Where the penultimate equality is due to the [Cassini identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities).

However, I'm struggling to see why these are the *only* solutions. I've tried some basic analysis with the norm in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ (since the Fibonacci numbers seems to have a particular attachment to $\sqrt{5}$) but came up mostly fruitless. How can we demonstrate that *every* $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ which produces a nonnegative integer $S$ must be of the form $x = \frac{F_{2n}}{F_{2n+1}}$?

Comment: The same link contains: https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/6-3/lind.pdf
From the equation you get the discriminant to be $(S+1)^2+4S^2=b^2$ which can be written as $5S^2+2S+1=b^2$ equivalent to $(5S+1)^2-5b^2=-4$. In the link they solve this diophantine equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's binary quadratic forms, indefinite. Say $\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}  = k$  is a positive integer. We have $x = k - kx - k x^2$ and $k-(k+1)x - k x^2 =0,$ and we demand $x$   rational.

So far, $ k x^2 +(k+1)x - k=0.$  The Quadratic Formula says
$$      x = \frac{-1-k \pm \sqrt{(k+1)^2 +(2k)^2}}{2k}      $$ so
in order to have $x$ rational, we demand
$$   (k+1)^2 + (2 k)^2 = w^2  $$

There are two cases, both need a diagram. WHEN $k$  is even, $\gcd( k+1, 2k) = 1.$  Thus we have a primitive Pythagorean triple. The requirement is that there be integers $m,n$ coprime and  not both odd, with $2mn=2k, m^2 - n^2 = k+1. $  Thus  $mn=k$    and
$$   m^2 - mn - n^2 = 1.$$
Negating both sides gives
$$  n^2 + nm - m^2 = -1$$
All solutions of this can be shown on Conway's topograph, I usually  write the form as $x^2 + xy - y^2 $  because it is Gauss-Lagrange reduced...
[image]
The diagram shows that the value of $x^2 + xy - y^2$  is unchanged by the mapping (same idea  as Vieta Jumping)
$$  (x,y)  \mapsto (x+y, x+2y)  $$
and a little fiddling shows that the $(x,y)$ pairs  (with $x,y \geq 0$) and $x^2 + xy - y^2 = -1$ are
$$ (0,1), (1,2), (3,5), (8,13), (21,34), (55, 89) $$  and so on. Indeed, inverting the mapping to $  (x,y)  \mapsto (2x-y, -x+y)  $  takes any pair   back to $(0,1),$  this giving the proof of Fibonacci-ness

Then  we go back to $k=mn$  which is, in the diagram, $k=xy,$   after which the desired rational  number (originally called $x$ )  is
$$      x = \frac{-1-k \pm \sqrt{(k+1)^2 +(2k)^2}}{2k}      $$
The values of $k$    are
$$ 0, 2, 15, 104, 714, 4895,  $$
with $ k_{n+2} = 7 k_{n+1}  - k_n + 1$

SECOND CASE: when $k$ is odd, we may write $k = 2j+1$  and reach $(j+1)^2 +( 2j+1)^2 = w^2.$  The two numbers $j+1, 2j+1$ are coprime, the latter odd, thus $j+1$ is even and $j$ odd. Once again, $j+1 = 2mn$ so that $2j+2 = 4mn, $ while
$2j+1 = m^2 - n^2 $  As $2j+1 - (2j+2) = -1,$   we find
$$m^2 - 4mn - n^2 = -1$$  I would usually switch to
$$  n^2 + 4nm - m^2 = 1.  $$  I don't expect I have a diagram ready for this exact form.

As is a requirement for representing $1,$   all $(n,m)$  pairs arise  by beginning with $(1,0) $  and applying the automorphism matrix  generator to reach mapping
$$  (n,m)    \mapsto  (n+4m, 4n+17m)$$
The first few pairs with both nonnegative are
$$  (1,0), (1,4), ( 17, 72), (305, 1292), (5473, 23184), ...$$
Both sequences, $1,1, 17, 305, 5473, ... $   and
$0, 4, 72, 1292, 23184$ obey the recurrence
$n_{j+2}  = 18 n_{j+1} - n_j$   and  $m_{j+2}  = 18 m_{j+1} - m_j.$   For this one,
$k = m^2 - n^2 $  and begins
$$ -1,  15, 4895, 1576239, 507544127, 163427632719,  52623190191455,  16944503814015855, ...$$
Here we have recurrence
$$ k_{i+2}= 322 k_{i+1}  - k_i + 64  $$
If we name $w_i = \sqrt{5k_i^2 + 2 k_i + 1},$  beginning with $k=-1$   we get sequence
$$    2,   34,  10946,  3524578,  1134903170,   365435296162,  117669030460994, $$

$$ w_{i+2}= 322 w_{i+1}  - w_i   $$

Comment: Brilliant! A lot of this is out of my comfort zone, but this explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @SilvioMayolo  I posted a second answer with, well, resources about the Conway topograph.

Answer (score 1):

Here are other questions where the Conway Topograph was relevant, in several I posted a diagram.

Producing the diagram is algorithmic in some ways. I have simple programs  to get the numbers right. Professors have asked about software to make these, I don't see why not. It is the final graphics that takes more  background than I have.

At the end I also list four books that discuss the topograph. The book by Hatcher is most similar to my choices; on the whole, I put in more information in one diagram than these authors.

[Another quadratic Diophantine equation: How do I proceed?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81917/another-quadratic-diophantine-equation-how-do-i-proceed/144794#144794)

[How to find solutions of $x^2-3y^2=-2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228356/how-to-find-solutions-of-x2-3y2-2/228405#228405)

[Generate solutions of Quadratic Diophantine Equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342284/generate-solutions-of-quadratic-diophantine-equation/345128#345128)

[Why can't the Alpertron solve this Pell-like equation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487051/why-cant-the-alpertron-solve-this-pell-like-equation/487063#487063)

[Finding all solutions of the Pell-type equation $x^2-5y^2 = -4$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512621/finding-all-solutions-of-the-pell-type-equation-x2-5y2-4/512649#512649)

[If $(m,n)\in\mathbb Z_+^2$ satisfies $3m^2+m = 4n^2+n$ then $(m-n)$ is a perfect square.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680972/if-m-n-in-mathbb-z-2-satisfies-3m2m-4n2n-then-m-n-is-a-perfect-square/686351#686351)

[how to solve binary form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=m$, for integer and rational $ (x,y)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739752/how-to-solve-binary-form-ax2bxycy2-m-for-integer-and-rational-x-y/739765#739765)  ::::  69   55

[Find all integer solutions for the equation $|5x^2 - y^2| = 4$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742181/find-all-integer-solutions-for-the-equation-5x2-y2-4/756972#756972)

[Positive integer $n$ such that $2n+1$ , $3n+1$ are both perfect squares](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822503/positive-integer-n-such-that-2n1-3n1-are-both-perfect-squares/822517#822517)

[Maps of primitive vectors and Conway's river, has anyone built this in SAGE?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078450/maps-of-primitive-vectors-and-conways-river-has-anyone-built-this-in-sage/1078979#1078979)

[Infinitely many systems of $23$ consecutive integers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091310/infinitely-many-systems-of-23-consecutive-integers/1093382#1093382)

[Solve the following equation for x and y:](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132187/solve-the-following-equation-for-x-and-y/1132347#1132347)  <1,-1,-1>

[Finding integers of the form $3x^2 + xy - 5y^2$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers, using diagram via arithmetic progression](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132799/finding-integers-of-the-form-3x2-xy-5y2-where-x-and-y-are-integers)

[Small integral representation as $x^2-2y^2$ in Pell's equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221178/small-integral-representation-as-x2-2y2-in-pells-equation/1221280#1221280)

[Solving the equation $ x^2-7y^2=-3 $ over integers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404023/solving-the-equation-x2-7y2-3-over-integers/1404126#1404126)

[Solutions to Diophantine Equations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599211/solutions-to-diophantine-equations/1600010#1600010)

[How to prove that the roots of this equation are integers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667323/how-to-prove-that-the-roots-of-this-equation-are-integers/1667380#1667380)

[Does the Pell-like equation $X^2-dY^2=k$ have a simple recursion like $X^2-dY^2=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719280/does-the-pell-like-equation-x2-dy2-k-have-a-simple-recursion-like-x2-dy2)

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737385/if-d1-is-a-squarefree-integer-show-that-x2-dy2-c-gives-some-bounds-i/1737824#1737824 "seeds"

[Find all natural numbers $n$ such that $21n^2-20$ is a perfect square.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772594/find-all-natural-numbers-n-such-that-21n2-20-is-a-perfect-square/1773319#1773319)

[Is there a simple proof that if $(b-a)(b+a) = ab - 1$, then $a, b$ must be Fibonacci numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549380/is-there-a-simple-proof-that-if-b-aba-ab-1-then-a-b-must-be-fibon/2549440#2549440) 1,1,-1; 1,11

[To find all integral solutions of $3x^2 - 4y^2 = 11$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579293/to-find-all-integral-solutions-of-3x2-4y2-11/2579305#2579305)

[How do we solve pell-like equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778825/how-do-we-solve-pell-like-equations/3778953#3778953)

[Diophantine equation $x^2 + xy − 3y^2 = 17$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804117/diophantine-equation-x2-xy-%e2%88%92-3y2-17/3804236#3804236) <1,1,-3>

[http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/conwaysens.pdf)   (Conway)

[https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNbook.pdf](https://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/TN/TNbook.pdf)    (Hatcher)

http://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/                  (Weissman)

http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387955872             (Stillwell)